# No consigo abrir un archivo .jar ejecutable con doble click

Tags: java, jar

la cuestión es simple, no soy capaz de abrir ningun jar ejecutable con doble click, en la consola compruebo si la version de java y javac son la misma y son la misma ( estuve mirando y podia ser este error).
En el path tengo lo siguiente: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Son las dos unicas variables que tienen java. 
Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: Y ya le dijiste a Windows con qué abrir los archivos de ese tipo? Con el path no basta para definir ese comportamiento

Comment: qué sale si le haces un link y el link lo arrastras a la consola cmd?

Comment: ya lo tengo definido (openJDK plataform binary) .

Comment: Con link te refieres a acceso directo?

Comment: @alexnuñezperez También me pasa lo mismo. He intentado de mil maneras y nada. Así que una "solución" rápida fue crear un archivo .bat y agregar en el, el siguiente comando: `java -jar myJar.jar` y luego simplemente le das clic al .bat creado y listo, el .jar se ejecutará.

Comment: @alexnuñezperez Si el .jar lo tienes en una ruta especifica, debes usar comillas en el comando. Como por ejemplo: `java -jar "C:\myJar.jar"`